# Como configurar a página inicial do meu site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Geralmente eu crio meus sites em `MVC` usando o template padrão que vem no `Visual Studio`.

Hoje criei um novo projeto sem usar um template e, ao testá-lo, recebi um erro:

> Um documento padrão não está configurado para a URL solicitada, e a pesquisa no diretório não está habilitada no servidor.

Quero saber como faço para configurar a página inicial do meu site.

Obs: Tenho apenas um `HomeController` e uma `Index.cshtml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alterar o arquivo `RouteConfig.cs` da pasta `App_Start` e preencher com o seguinte código:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",
                "",
                new { Controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
        }
    }
```

Fonte: https://devbla.wordpress.com/2013/06/24/configurando-a-pagina-inicial-de-um-projeto-mvc/